# How do I parse unknown encoding file?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to parse a file with extension with vmd (Vocaloid Motion Data 0002). I do not know what encoding it uses. I have attempted using UTF-8, UTF-16, CS_ASCII and Windows-31j (Shift JIS), but none of them worked (but based on what I know, most of UTF-8 should resolve since the byte is 2 for most of characters).

```
String testFile = rawFilePath+"/test.vmd";
BufferedWriter bw = null;
FileWriter fw = null;
fw = new FileWriter(outputPath+"/newFile.txt");
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
BufferedReader fBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(testFile), "UTF-8"));  //US-ASCII windows-31j
int count=0;
String line;
while ((line = fBr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    bw.write(line);
    bw.write("\r\n");
    count++;
    if(count > 3) { //print small portion of a larger file for testing
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Both print and the output file writes something like this:

```
???~?N ??????????P ?Z???^?[    ??kkkkkkkk
```

I was wondering if this is an encoding issue, or some other issue?  How do I parse readable data from this?

Comment: What makes you think it's text content? Binary files don't have an encoding, and unless the vendor has documented the format you can't *decode* the file without reverse engineering it.

Comment: Because it was written in the file formatter http://mikumikudance.wikia.com/wiki/VMD_file_format under section File header

Comment: That's not a text file format. Read the documentation more carefully. It's a binary file format specification. Because the text uses *string* in a few places does not magically make it a text file.

Comment: @logger its binary, use DataInputStream using appropriate methods as in file format spec.

Comment: https://github.com/chototsu/MikuMikuStudio/blob/master/engine/src/mmd/projectkyoto/mmd/file/VMDFile.java might give you a head-start.

Comment: Re, "most of UTF-8 should resolve since the byte is 2 for most of characters."  Not sure what you're saying there, but the majority of code points in Unicode's Basic Multilingual Plane have three-byte encodings in UTF-8.  While, on the other hand, the majority of characters in English-language text will have single-byte encodings in UTF-8.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vocaloid Motion Data is binary data (as mentioned in the link you provided), so you can't just convert it to text and hope for the best. That means, you can't use readers but must use `InputStreams`. There is an InputStream called `DataInputStream` that can read ints and floats if they are encoded in VMD in the same way Java expects them to be. You can try it out, if reasonable values come up, you're golden, otherwise you have to read in the single bytes and calculate with the values to create the corresponding result yourself (e.g. if the data is least significant byte first ordering, etc.)

So code that reads in VMD could look like this (in lack of a real file, this should just be seen as illustration. There are things missing like checking that we actually read the number of bytes into the arrays or if we reached the end of the stream prematurely, etc.

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("rawFilePath", "test.vmd"))) {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] nameBytes = new byte[15];
    dis.read(nameBytes);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nameBytes.length; i++) {
        if (nameBytes[i] == 0) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    String name = new String(nameBytes, 0, index, "8859_1");
    // Java ints are signed, so to keep an unsigned int we need long
    long frameNumber = dis.readInt() & 0xffffffff;
    float boneXPosCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    float boneYPosCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    float boneZPosCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    float boneXRotCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    float boneYRotCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    float boneZRotCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    float boneWRotCoordinate = dis.readFloat();
    byte[] interpolationData = new byte[64];
    dis.read(interpolationData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to examine it as a `byte` stream. And during that inspection, decode the first few bytes by hand, according to how encoding is done. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark for some good information on starting to work with UTF encoding.

Comment: This is only relevant if you know you're reading a text file, which this poster is not. There isn't a BOM in binary data content, and if you happen to encounter similar content in the first few bytes doesn't make it accurate.

Comment: Interesting. The specs (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#page-6) seem to specify a `a stream of UCS characters` which is irrespective of the underlying storage type. It also states that it appear at the `beginning of the text stream`, and that `it is optional`. So there may not be a lot of luck going down this path.

Comment: The file spec the OP provided at http://mikumikudance.wikia.com/wiki/VMD_file_format seems to say otherwise. 4-byte floats and integers aren't text.